# How to wrap Vite build in IIFE and still have all the dependencies bundled into a single file?

Tags: vite, esbuild

I'm building a chrome extension using Vite as my build tool. **The main problem** is during minification and mangling there are a lot of global variables created. After injecting my script to the page they conflict with already defined variables on window object.

I imagine the perfect solution would be to have my entire script wrapped in IIFE. I tried using `esbuild.format = 'iife'`. The resulting build is in fact wrapped in IIFE, however all the imports are not inlined. Instead resulting script is like 15 lines long with a bunch of `require` statements, which obviously does not work in the browser.

This is my config file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  esbuild: {
    format: 'iife',
  },
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: resolve(__dirname, './src/web/index.ts'),
      output: {
        dir: resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        entryFileNames: 'web.js',
        assetFileNames: 'style.css',
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
});
```

I'm currently using [this hack](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7188) so to say to wrap my build in IIFE (for this I removed the `esbuild.format` option).

Answer (score 6):

Hey I am doing the exact same thing! And I also noticed the unminified variables and functions can clash with random code in a webpage.

From what I researched myself on this topic, you shouldn't change `esbuild` build options with Vite as that will prevent Rollup from transforming the output. Instead, you should use `format: 'iife'` in the `rollupOptions` of your `vite.config`. However, in my case (and yours I believe), I have to output multiple bundles since the extension code can't share modules amongst each other. Which will crash when you set the format to 'iife' due to:

```
Invalid value for option "output.inlineDynamicImports" - multiple inputs are not supported when "output.inlineDynamicImports" is true.
```

The only solution in my case seems to be to either use multiple `vite.configs` (I already have two) for each of my bundle with single `input` entry point and format as 'iife'. Or, as you did, just write the self-invoking function yourself with some hacky script. Seems though there aren't any perfect solutions as of now.

EDIT: Okay, got it working. This is my `vite.config.ts` ([the project](https://github.com/TeemuKoivisto/prosemirror-dev-toolkit)):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

import path from 'path'

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({}), tsconfigPaths()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js'
      },
      input: {
        inject: path.resolve('./src/inject.ts'),
        proxy: path.resolve('./src/proxy.ts'),
        'pop-up': path.resolve('./pop-up.html')
      },
      plugins: [
        {
          name: 'wrap-in-iife',
          generateBundle(outputOptions, bundle) {
            Object.keys(bundle).forEach((fileName) => {
              const file = bundle[fileName]
              if (fileName.slice(-3) === '.js' && 'code' in file) {
                file.code = `(() => {\n${file.code}})()`
              }
            })
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I finally made it by adding the `iife` into rollup options. In my case I have separate vite config for each script (background, web and content). Honestly I'm not sure why I ended up with three configs, but as for now I'm happy with the solution.

Comment: For me this worked without iife option in rollup. I also have multiple inputs and iife does not seem to work with multiple inputs. But this custom plugin works for now

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I made it working with this config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: resolve(__dirname, './src/web/index.ts'),
      output: {
        format: 'iife',
        dir: resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        entryFileNames: 'web.js',
        assetFileNames: 'style.css',
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
});
```

They key part is `format: 'iife'` inside `build.rollupOptions.output`.